# Magento2 Create Account with password Webapi not working

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, rest-api

Can anyone let me know how to use Rest webapi to create new customer account with password? i have used following webapi in postman but it won't allow me to add password field,rest fields working fine, Please do let me know if anyone have done this kind of things.please find screenshot of webapi I have used to create account:

rest/V1/customers

[image: postman api]

[image: error log]

Comment: you're passing wrong array key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Register Customer using API**

> webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/customers" method="POST">
<service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="createAccount"/>
<resources>
    <resource ref="anonymous"/>
</resources>
</route>
```

url `http://<magento-host>/rest/V1/customers`

> url action :: POST

**Body > raw > JSON(application/json)**

```
{
"customer":{
    "email":"Test@example.com",
    "firstname":"Aditya",
    "lastname":"Shah",
    "websiteId":"1",
    "addresses":[
        {
            "customer_id":"1",
            "firstname":"Aditya",
            "lastname":"Shah",
            "company":"ABC Manufacturing",
            "telephone":"555-555-5555",
            "city":"Boston",
            "region":"Massachusetts",
            "postcode":"02115",
            "country_id":"US",
            "street":[
                "404 Main Street",
                "PO Box 321"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
 "password": "Account@123"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya, it worked for me, i was putting password field inside customer object as per my understanding, your solution worked like a charm!!!! Thanks a lot.